# how to use expect in shell

Tags: shell

Here is my shell script:

```
cd /home/debian/goagent  
python ./server/uploader.zip   

expect -c "  
set timeout 5   

expect {   
timeout exit   
\"APPID:\"   
}   
send \"haha\r\"
```

Why my script did not run?
The "haha" (my APPID) is not be input into the APPID, why?

Comment: I tried to format your code and question, but I cannot make sense of either. What does it mean to run Python on a `.zip` file? What tool are you trying to drive with `expect`?

Answer (score 0):

if you download  goagent  from  https://code.google.com/p/goagent/
you can see  how to use  goagent.
i want to  input something automatically to run my  script.

people  use  goagent to  see more thing ,i just want to make my script  run automatically